# Question on boundedness

Tags: general-topology, partial-differential-equations

Page number 479 in partial differential equation by Evans book how to say that the derivative of I is bounded on bounded sets

Comment: I think you'll get better answers if you put a little more work into the question.

Comment: okay thank you for your advise

Comment: The book by Evans has two editions; page numbers depend on the edition. It is better to describe the context of the unclear passage, so it can be reliably located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional $I$ is assumed to have a continuous derivative. Of course, a continuous function on a Hilbert space need not be bounded on bounded sets. I think this is why Evans made a remark on page 477:

> **Remark.** The theory we will develop below holds if $I\in C^1(H;\mathbb R)$, but the proofs will be greatly streamlined provided we additionally assume 
>   $$ I':H\to H  \text{ is Lipschitz continuous on bounded subsets of $H$}\tag2$$

He then defines $\mathcal C$ to be the set of functions $I\in C^1(H;\mathbb R)$ that satisfy (2).

Clearly, Lipschitz continuous functions are bounded on bounded sets, in any metric space.

The assumptions in the argument in question include $I\in\mathcal C$.